# how to get email addresses from mail composer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How do you get the email addresses that the mail composer sent to was?

I tried looking at this delegate:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{


}
```

but it seems that there's no way to get the email addresses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The interface is designed such that what the user enters is not visible to you.

If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to suggest an alternate API or solution.

Comment: I have a mail composer, which is to invite people to use the app, I need to track how many email address has this user sent the invite to and also need it to track duplicates. Any idea?

Comment: You can't do this with the built-in mail view controller. You would have to roll your own, but Apple frowns on tracking users by email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the email addresses from mail composer.

One suggestion:
If you know the name of the intended recipients, you can get the email addresses from the address book. Note that you will need to inform your users of the app's action, preferably with an option for them to proceed or cancel the action.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through my same question, on which finally I concluded that There are no official Apple's API to get email addresses...

[Retrieve E-mail in In-app in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712481/retrieve-e-mail-in-in-app-in-iphone/11153848#11153848)